# Params :pagination not found! (RuntimeError) grape rails

Tags: pagination, kaminari, grape-api

**I have face this issue when I was implementing pagination using grape kaminari gem to show a list.**

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't included `Grape-Kaminari` into your **base.rb** file. Please add this line

```
include Grape::Kaminari
```

into your **base.rb** file and I think it will solve your issue.
Here is a demo image: [grape-kaminari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rym1U.png)